# EVM is sandboxed program execution environment

Tags: evm

I read following content about EVM:

> It is vital to also note that EVM operates in a sandboxed environment- it is totally isolated from the main Blockchain network, and works perfectly as a testing environment. Therefore anybody who would want to create a smart contract using EVM can do so without interfering with other Blockchain operations.

Sorry I can't understand this. I think that we have developers which create Smart Contracts (SC) and we don’t do the development process in  EVM and EVM is basically used for the execution of SC. I can't understand what type of testing is mentioned above. For testing of SC we have several tools (like Oyente, Remix and so on) which are not part of EVM.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Where is it from? The intention seems to be that you can test in the EVM without concern about the rest of the blockchain infrastructure: p2p, blocks, transactions, mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite agree with the comment either. EVM is a vital part of Ethereum blockchain and it's not isolated in any sense. It's a *virtual* machine, so it's a rather abstract construct which doesn't exist in any physical place but is distributed among all nodes. EVM refers to the execution environment and it's run on top of blockchain.

I guess in theory you could use some other type of network with EVM but it would take quite some effort - it's currently quite tied to the Ethereum blockchain.

In a sense the blockchain is a sandboxed environment - it has very limited means of inputting information into it. And the EVM operates in the blockchain. So one might still claim that it operates in a sandboxes environment but I don't see how it could be said to be an isolated from the blockchain.

Comment: Right. Specifically for the public EVM blockchain, we can't say that but if we are using Truffle then we can say that EVM like software operates in isolation. Does the geth client works in complete isolation? For the test purposes, we use the word "EVM instrumentation", which requires isolation from the main blockchain, how this is done?

Comment: I don't know what is "complete isolation" - a program is rather useless if it doesn't take input and doesn't produce output. Geth connects the "real world" to blockchain so it's not isolated. And I'm not familiar with the term EVM instrumentation.